# Converting a String to Bitmap, and Store it to SD Card

Tags: java, php, android, json

I wanted to store an Image to SD card by first converting the returned JSONObject that contains base64, then convert it to bitmap. I tried the code below, but nothing seems working.

Php code to return JSON object:

```
            $img = $row["imageName"];
        $b64img = mysql_real_escape_string($b64img);
        $b64img = base64_encode ($img);
        $product["imageName"] = $b64img;
```

Java Code that retrieves the returned JSON:

```
for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);


byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(c.getString(TAG_IMAGE_NAME), Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);

String fileN = (i+1)+".jpg";

OutputStream fOut = null;
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/FinalTestforDatabase/",fileN);
                try {
                fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            decodedByte.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
                            try {
                                fOut.flush();
                            } catch (IOException e2) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e2.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            try {
                                fOut.close();
                            } catch (IOException e1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }

                try {
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),file.getAbsolutePath(),file.getName(),file.getName());
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
}
```

Comment: in device side have you successfully get the JSON data?and have you tried to print the bitmap to an imageview to test it?

Comment: Yes, I printed decodedString and the c.getString(TAG_IMAGE_NAME), but I am getting errors when displaying the bitmap into imgView.setImageBitmap(decodedByte ). Anything wrong with the code above?

Comment: which error you got.??

Comment: yes please tell us what error did you got?and please print the stacktrace here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to make sure that the main folder is created first to contain  the images, then after that the code below did the trick. The next thing it to create a new folder to contains the images so `"/FolderName/FolderName2/"` is what I need.

```
                    OutputStream fOut = null;
                        File file = new File(
                                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                        + "/FolderName/FolderName2/",
                                fileN);
                        try {
                            fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        decodedByte.compress(
                                Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
                        try {
                            fOut.flush();
                        } catch (IOException e2) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e2.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            fOut.close();
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        try {
                            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                                    getContentResolver(),
                                file.getAbsolutePath(),
                                    file.getName(), file.getName());
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```